# Catch exception in asyncio gather

Tags: python, asynchronous, exception, async-await

Suppose there are several coroutines that we send to the event loop

```
task_list = [task1(), task2(), task3()]
res = asyncio.gather(*task_list, return_exceptions=True)
```

Regarding documentation

> If return_exceptions is True, exceptions are treated the same as
> successful results, and aggregated in the result list.

I.e. if for example task2 returns an error, the result will be

```
res = [task1_result, task2_error, task3_result]
```

The result is further processed in another process, and I would like to pass some default value if there is an error in the response. The question is how to check for an exception in the event_loop response. Smth like (**warning pseudo code**!)

```
response = default if any(res is Error) else res
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `map` function to replace errors in result list by default value. For checking if result is an error `isinstance(result, Exception)` can be used. Like so:

```
task_list = [task1(), task2()]
res = await asyncio.gather(*task_list, return_exceptions=True)  # res = ["result", ArithmeticError()]
res = list(map(lambda r: r if not isinstance(r, Exception) else default_value, res))  # res = ["result", None]
```